# Can datastore input in google dataflow pipeline be processed in a batch of N entries at a time?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud, dataflow

I am trying to execute a dataflow pipeline job which would execute one function on **N entries at a time** from datastore. In my case this function is sending batch of 100 entries to some REST service as payload. This means that I want to go through all entries from one datastore entity, and send *100 batched entries at once* to some outside REST service.

**My current solution**

1. Read input from datastore
2. Create as many keys as there are workers specified in pipeline options (1 worker = 1 key).
3. Group by key, so that we get iterator as output (iterator input in step no.4)
4. Programatically batch users in temporary list and send them as a batch to the REST endpoint.

Above described scenario in pseudo code (ignoring details):

```java
final int BATCH_SIZE = 100;

// 1. Read input from datastore
pipeline.apply(DatastoreIO.readFrom(datasetId, query))

    // 2. create keys to be used in group by so we get iterator in next task
    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<DatastoreV1.Entity, KV<String, EntryPOJO>>() {
        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            String key = generateKey(c);
            EntryPOJO entry = processEntity(c);
            c.output(KV.of(key, entry));
        }
    }))

    // 3. Group by key
    .apply(GroupByKey.create())

    // 4. Programatically batch users
    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<EntryPOJO>>() {
        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            List<EntryPOJO> batchedEntries = new ArrayList<>();
            for (EntryPOJO entry : c.element().getValue()) {
                if (batchedEntries.size() >= BATCH_SIZE) {
                    sendToRESTEndpoint(batchedEntries);
                    batchedEntries = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                batchedEntries.add(entry);
            }
            sendToRESTEndpoint(batchedEntries);
        }
    }));
```

**Main problem with my current solution**

GroupByKey blocks the execution of last ParDo (blocks step no.4) until all entries are assigned to a key.

Solution generally works, but I would like to do everything in parallel (**send batch of 100 entries to the REST endpoint immediately after they are loaded from datastore**), which is not possible with my current solution, since GroupByKey doesn't output any data until every entry from database is fetched and inserted into key-value pair. So execution is actually in 2 steps: 1. Fetch all the data from datastore and assign it a key, 2. Process entries as batch

**Question**

So what I would like to know is if there is some existing feature to be able to do this. Or at least to get Iterable without GroupByKey step so that batching function task doesn't need to wait for data to be dumped.

Comment: [Onur Ozer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11626881) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66591191) saying "Anyone has still similar issues should check https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/groupintobatches/"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can batch these elements up within your `DoFn`. For example:

```
final int BATCH_SIZE = 100;

pipeline
  // 1. Read input from datastore  
  .apply(DatastoreIO.readFrom(datasetId, query))

  // 2. Programatically batch users
  .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<DatastoreV1.Entity, Iterable<EntryPOJO>>() {

    private final List<EntryPOJO> accumulator = new ArrayList<>(BATCH_SIZE);

    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
      EntryPOJO entry = processEntity(c);
      accumulator.add(c);
      if (accumulator.size() >= BATCH_SIZE) {
        c.output(accumulator);
        accumulator = new ArrayList<>(BATCH_SIZE);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void finishBundle(Context c) throws Exception {
      if (accumulator.size() > 0) {
        c.output(accumulator);
      }
    }
  });

  // 3. Consume those bundles
  .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<Iterable<EntryPOJO>, Object>() {
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        sendToRESTEndpoint(batchedEntries);
    }
  }));
```

You could also combine steps 2 and 3 in a single `DoFn` if you didn't want the separate "batching" step.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, solved my problem. Thanks for a quick response.

I was trying to implement it this way at first but I overlooked "finishBundle" method, which is crucial if you want to process elements remaining in accumulator.

Comment: You should also reset the list in finishBundle (or at least startBundle) as DoFns can be reused (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-38)

Comment: How can I replicate this same behaviour using the Python SDK?