# Writing to memcache from within a streaming dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to write to memcache from a streaming data flow pipeline? or do I need to write to a pubsub and create another compute engine or app engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For redis I created DoFn with redis client. 
It is possible to do some tricks if you need batch writing. For example: 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065109/can-datastore-input-in-google-dataflow-pipeline-be-processed-in-a-batch-of-n-ent/35068341#35068341)

Comment: Thanks, I've switched to redis now also.  I wasn't batch writing but this link is insightful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Dataflow workers can communicate with any external services that you need; they are just VMs with no special restrictions or permissions.

If you are just writing out data to memcache, the [Sink](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/Sink.java) API will likely be useful

Comment: Thanks but could you be more specific.  Can you give me an example Sink call that also shows how I authenticate ?

Comment: If you can go into your use case a bit more, I can give an example of how to use the Sink API to implement it.
With regards to authentication, for communicating with any Google-provided service you can use the credentials in options.getGcpCredential()

Comment: From the dataflow custom sink page it says that you can only write bounded data but I need to do it from a streaming pipeline."You can use the extensible API to create custom sources that read either bounded (batch) or unbounded (streaming) data, and to create sinks that write bounded data only."

Comment: I have a streaming dataflow pipeline that is reading a pubsub and writing the data to a BigQuery table.  I want to also be able to rollup that data and write the rollups to memcache for quick current access from clients and then also write those rollups to datastore.  I would like to do this all from the same pipeline.

Comment: Ah, for now in streaming, you can just make direct calls to the memcache API from a DoFn

Comment: Yes but the memcache is not residing in the dataflow vm (or do you need to ssh in and install it?).  I don't want to create an app engine on it's own just to hold the cache.