# Why doesn't DoFnTester support outputs in finishBundle() any more?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have some functions that process the elements from a bundle in batches. They need to output the last batch in the finishBundle() method.

Something like described in the answer to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065109/can-datastore-input-in-google-dataflow-pipeline-be-processed-in-a-batch-of-n-ent/35068341#35068341).

In the latest Dataflow 2.0.0-beta1 release, which is based on Beam 0.4.0, the DoFnTester throws UnsupportedOperationException from its finishBundle() method if the function under test invokes the output method on the context there.

Is there any reason for this behavior change? Is output from DoFn.finishBundle() not supported anymore during runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regression in DoFnTester.  I've filed a bug against Beam [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1282)

Comment: Thank you for the help, Daniel.

Comment: In fact, it has never worked properly except for globally windowed test data.